# spark and httpclient dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have a spark application that runs in YARN. One of the dependencies in application needs httpclient 4.5.1. I explicitly include that as a dependency on my pom.
 However, when I run the application in YARN. I get the following stacktrace

```
 Factory method 'createClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
```

Looks like a dependency issue with Spark. Is there any way that I could override httpclient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I used was to run the spark application in YARN with the flag
   spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true

That fixed my issue.

Comment: This did not work for me, caused other things to bomb out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this method [was added in httpclient 4.4](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html#setValidateAfterInactivity(int)). The fact that the run reports that is a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` implies that your class is finding another version of this class (`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`) on the Spark platform. Maybe another version of Apache HTTP Client is bundled with Spark?

I suggest you use the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) to create a self-contained application such that it can (hopefully) use the classes and JAR's that it needs.

Comment: Spark assembly jar has an older version of httpclient.